# Are Red Court Vampires/Infected affected by the saliva of other Red Court Vampires/Infected?

Tags: lore, dresden-files, campaign-settings

In The Dresden Files RPG, Red Court Vampires(RCV)/Infected have the supernatural power Addictive Saliva (YW162).  The power itself does not say anything about it conferring immunity to the saliva of other RCV, and the books don't address that either.

Is there any rule/reference that I might be missing that would say for sure if they are or are not immune to the effects of the saliva of other RCV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you took the magical route for the saliva, I would say that it offers a small degree of immunity based on the power differential between the Red Court vampires.

If you took a medical route, I would say that the saliva is akin to a venom therefore they are immune.  Otherwise, they would not be able to function because they would be constantly under the effect of their own venom.

I do not think that the books describe at any point any red courts fighting each other so it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on what happens with Red Court infected and whether they're immune, but it's down in the book wiki that full Red Court vampires are apparently fully immune to the saliva and it's effects:

> Its effects on human beings can be counteracted by a potion, while
>   Red Court vampires are immune to it

So, I'd presume that since the RPG operates by the same lore, the same would apply there.